# How to combine multiple collection data of same type into single collection in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

In some implementation, I am getting list of collections as a result which are of same type. But I need a single collection as a output which include data from all collections.

**Example :**
I am getting the below result. ( This is Dynamic list. It may of N number of collections)

> TYPE_DATA_COLL(TYPE_DATA(1,abc,1001),TYPE_DATA(2,efg,1002),TYPE_DATE(3,xyz,1003))
> TYPE_DATA_COLL(TYPE_DATA(8,www,1008),TYPE_DATA(9,qqq,1009))
> TYPE_DATA_COLL(TYPE_DATA(4,aaa,1004),TYPE_DATA(5,efg,1005),TYPE_DATE(6,xyz,1006),TYPE_DATA(7,fff,1007))

But I need like

> TYPE_DATA_COLL(TYPE_DATA(1,abc,1001),TYPE_DATA(2,efg,1002),TYPE_DATE(3,xyz,1003),TYPE_DATA(8,www,1008),TYPE_DATA(9,qqq,1009),TYPE_DATA(4,aaa,1004),TYPE_DATA(5,efg,1005),TYPE_DATE(6,xyz,1006),TYPE_DATA(7,fff,1007))

Comment: SQL implements the sum of two numbers (expr_1 + expr_2) and also an aggregate `SUM` function. It (or at least the Oracle version) implements the binary operation `UNION MULTISET` for two operands (for example two nested tables), but it does **not** implement the corresponding **aggregate function**, where you combine any number of nested tables into a single one, similar to aggregate `SUM`. So, unless you can aggregate all members from the outset (and instead you **must** go through the partial lists first), the only choice is to split the lists and then recombine.

Comment: To recombine, you can use the `COLLECT` aggregate function. But this seems like doing too much work. It would help more if you would show how you ended up with the partial lists in the first place; likely the aggregation of individual records into lists should be modified to get what you need in one go, but we can't help if we don't see your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks as if `multiset union` would do (see line #8). A simple example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    type myt is table of number;
  3
  4    l_one myt := myt (1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
  5    l_two myt := myt (0, 2, 4, 6, 8);
  6    l_res myt;
  7  begin
  8    l_res := l_one multiset union l_two;
  9
 10    for i in l_res.first .. l_res.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(l_res(i));
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
1
3
5
7
9
0
2
4
6
8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I don't know how you're getting that "dynamic list", but I guess you should be able to do it. If not, consider posting test case (code that returns collections you mentioned) so that we'd see what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my list is dynamic. I want to combine n number of collections into one

Comment: Re-read what I wrote at the end of the answer.